# FTPWebRequest: Unable to connect to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ftpwebrequest

I've written a site in ASP.NET which uses `FTPWebRequest` to download a text file from an FTP server every 15 seconds. When I run it on my computer, it works just fine. When I upload it to our server, the FTP download fails. No exception, it just returns 0 values.

I thought there might be an issue with the firewall, so I disabled the Windows firewall, and disabled outgoing firewall, same problem. Tried both active and passive FTP. Is it possible I need to change some settings in IIS Manager?

Running IIS 10 on Server 2012 R2, on the same VM with Exchange 2016.

Part of the code:

```
public static string[] GetTXT()
{
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.  
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("FTP address");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    request.UsePassive = false;    //tried it with true as well

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string result = (reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: Is there anything helpful in the FTP server logs?

Comment: Please clarify the following. The question title says "Unable to connect to server" but the question body says no exception. Which is it? Does "0 values" mean that the values it returns are zero, or that nothing is returned, or that a zero-length file is returned?

Comment: Nobody but you can help more in this case, as firewall configuration is complex https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7 Do use passive mode, and then open the necessary ports on server side. You might have tried to disable firewalls, but I doubt you have disabled the correct ones, so be patient and check again.

Comment: Check `write` permission of the account which runs production server.

Comment: Where can I find these FTP logs? All the logs I found are FTP server logs, but in my case I'm a client.
When I open my site, I can see it tries to download this TXT file, but after a couple of seconds all the values turn to zero. I guess this is the connection time out.
The firewalls I disabled are the build in windows firewall and the one on my Endian firewall (router). I don't think I can disable anything else that could block my traffic.
Currently I run the site as domain admin, it should have all the required  rights.

Comment: @JeroenChristiaen Yes, the server logs are the ones I meant. Can you compare the log entries for a working request (originated from your computer) to a failed request? As it does work from one computer and not another, it is unlikely to be a firewall issue because then there would be nothing at all from the failed request to be recorded in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually discovered I was publishing the site in a subfolder.
The root folder probably contained an older version.
Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

If just a download from the server `FTP`, I recommend this class [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) implemented by Microsoft for your method.

It maybe resolves your problem.

```
public static string[] GetTXT()
{   
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        var path = @"C:\local\path\file.txt";
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("log", "pass");
        client.DownloadFile("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.txt", path);
    }
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {

        return File.ReadAllLines(path);
    }
    //return something  
}
```

Comment: If it is indeed a firewall issue, then this code won't work either.